# Redirect to different route in Meteor if a object doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, flow-router

I have a route `postDetail` with path `/posts/:postId` using Flow Router.

I want to check if the post actually exists. If the post doesn't exists, I want to show the `postList` route instead.

How can I do this? I guess I can use `triggersEnter`; however, the data is subscribed in the template, so maybe I cannot use `triggersEnter` in the router.

A simple way would be to populate the template with a variable `doesExists` from the template helper, and just use

```
{{#if doesExists}}
  [...]
{{else}}
  {{> postList}}
{{/if}}
```

but I do not think it's a very smart way to do it because I have to do this in a lot of different templates and I am not able to redirect the user to the postList route with this approach.

Comment: I would reconsider this UX pattern. If a user expects to see the details of a given post, and instead sees a list of posts (or, even worse, is being redirected to it), without any indication that the post is not available, then I would consider this a usability issue.

Comment: You're right. I could probably use the pattern I wrote in my question; however, when a user has clicked a post, he sees a different layout with a subnavigation specific to this post, so the subnavigation becomes very weird when the post doesn't exists. Ideally, I could just use my `notFound` which is configured in Flow Router

Answer (score 0):

If you have Template level subscriptions like:

```
Template.YOUR_TEMPLATE_HERE.onCreated(function() {
  let self = this;
  self.autorun(function() {
    self.subscribe('posts');
  })
});
```

Then you can redirect with triggersEnter like so:

```
triggersEnter: [function(context, redirect) {
  if (Posts.find({_id:context.params.id}).count() < 1)
    redirect('/postslist');
}],
```